# Error while running an Octave script

Tags: matlab, octave

here is my octave script:

```
aReal=(dlmread('082023.csv')(2:end,2:9));
aForcast=(dlmread('082023.csv')(2:end,12:19));
difference= aReal-aForcast;
squareOfDifference=difference.*difference;
sumOfSquareOfDifference=sum(squareOfDifference);
meanSquareDeviations=sumOfSquareOfDifference/length(aReal);
rootMeanSquareDeviation=sqrt(meanSquareDeviations);
```

this is saved as working.m

while executing with the command

```
run working.m
```

it worked but now is returning error:

```
A(I,J): column index out of bounds; value 19 out of bound 18
error: called from '067bct521.m' in file /home/shaardul/Desktop/Acsv/working.m near line 23, column 9
error: called from:
error:   /usr/share/octave/3.6.4/m/miscellaneous/run.m at line 55, column 7
```

Comment: This means there are fewer than 19 columns in your CSV file. Sounds like you changed the contents of the file, since you said "it was working".

Comment: yeah there were two empty columns in between which were previously treated as column with all values zero by the code, but now after i go through the file appending some data, it is treating like those blank column do not exist. I am amazed.